# How to run custom appender in separate thread

Tags: java, multithreading, logging, logback

i just created my own appender as base of [Logback document chapter 4](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html) (see Writing your own Appender section).

Whatever is being logged at `INFO` level in my application, My appender gets invoked and post that message as http message to the `servlet` running on other end.

these kind of logic makes my application to slow down. because the appender runs on same thread which application is running. How do i make my appender to run in separate thread ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Logback is based on Log4J, you should be able to used asynchronous logging option. [See here](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#AsyncAppender) This makes sure that your logging process runs in a separate thread.

Comment: Great! its worked, also it has property to control the queue size,thanks Richie